# Change in Entropy and Spontaneity

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I was studying thermodynamics and got stuck with some questions. I am pointing them down.

1. I have studied that $\Delta S_{\text{total}}$
   accompanied by a spontaneous process is greater than 0. But is the converse true?
   I mean, will any process for which $\Delta S_{\text{total}}>0$ be spontaneous?
2. Is the $\Delta S_{\text{total}}$ for all reversible processes equal to 0?
3. Is $\Delta S_{\text{total}}$ for all irreversible process >0?

Please help me with the answers to these with some explanations for the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to all three questions is yes.  This is basically a statement of the 2nd law of thermodynamics.  There are two ways in which the entropy of a system can change: 1.  by entropy exchange with the surroundings and 2. by entropy generation.

Entropy exchange is like exchanging money between two bank accounts.  So any increase in the balance in one account is accompanied by an identical decrease in money in the other account.  So the net change in the amount of money is zero.  In a reversible process, only entropy exchange occurs.  So an increase in the entropy of the system is accompanied by an identical decrease in the entropy of the surroundings (and vice versa).  So the net change in entropy is zero.

Entropy generation is like gaining interest in one or both bank accounts.  So the interest in one or both accounts increase.  In an irreversible spontaneous process, there is entropy generation in addition to entropy exchange.  So the total entropy of the system plus surroundings increases in an irreversible spontaneous process.